# Calculate Amount of Product from Northwind

Tags: sql

How can I calculate the total amount for product after discount of each `EmployeeId` in Northwind database of SQL Server?

The tables used from Northwind database are:

- Employees
- Order details
- Products

Comment: Which is table field? Which is relation between the tables? Have you tried anything? If yes so show me

Answer (score 0):

If you are calculating amount for each EmployeeId 
you have to use one more table for join along with these tables

1. Orders
2. Products
3. Employees
4. Order Details

and your query should be

```
select O.EmployeeID,OD.ProductID,Sum(OD.UnitPrice*Quantity *(1-Discount)) as TotalAmount from Orders as o
inner join [Order Details] as OD on OD.OrderID=o.OrderID
inner join Products as p on p.ProductID=OD.ProductID
group by OD.ProductID,o.EmployeeID
order by OD.ProductID
```

Answer (score -1):

Write the code (Country, City, TotalCustomer) to show how many customers there are in each city in the country from the Northwind database

Comment: OP is looking for each EmployeeId